# kendoGrid popup edit cancel button removes existing row

Tags: kendo-grid

I have reviewed other answers to this question but none solve this problem. When using popup editor on the kendoGrid, cancel removes the row completely.
here's the code:

```
addWindow.element.find("#InventoryChecks").kendoGrid({
                               dataSource: {
                                        data: checkCallDetail.InventoryChecks,
                                        schema: {
                                            model: {
                                                id: "Id",
                                                fields: {
                                                    Id: { type: "number" },
                                                    BillOfLading: { type: "string" },
                                                    ReportedPieces: { type: "number" },
                                                    ReportedWeight: { type: "number" }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        aggregate: [ 
                                            { field: "ReportedPieces", aggregate:"sum" },
                                            { field: "ReportedWeight", aggregate: "sum" }]
                                    },
                                    height: 200,
                                    scrollable: true,
                                    toolbar: ["create"], 
                                    columns: [
                                        { field: "BillOfLading", title: "BOL", width: "100px", footerTemplate: "Total: " },
                                        { field: "ReportedPieces", title: "Quantity", width: "70px", footerTemplate: " #= sum # " },
                                        { field: "ReportedWeight", title: "Weight", width: "70px", footerTemplate: " #= sum # " },
                                        { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;"}
                                    ],
                                    editable: {
                                        mode: "popup",

                                    }
                                })
```

Any suggestions?